# Is it an anti pattern to use ng-init to run a function on the controller when view is loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, karma-jasmine

To make testing easier I have been initiating my controllers with `ng-init`

so that in my controller I have code like this

```
$scope.initiate = function () {
    myResource.makeXhrRequest();
}
```

and my view code looks like this

```
<div data-ng-init=initiate()"> ALL MY HTML IN HERE </div>
```

the benefit is that when I unit test I can have carefully test that `myResource.makeXhrRequest();` is called.

Without this approach I find that I have to mock up the `xhrRequest` on every test.

My question is "Is this considered an anti pattern?"

Comment: I would say that it is, considering the official documentation says not to do it.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#!/ "The only appropriate use of `ngInit` is for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`"  That being said, your question as asked is off topic, as it is directly asking for opinions.

Comment: I don't think it is off topic if your response is canonical.

Answer (score 0):

I personally only use ng-init when i want to reuse a controller/directive, but i want some view specific initialization to be made. i don't think is an anti-pattern as long as you don't abuse it